# HTML5 change the name <details> when displayed

Tags: html

I'm using the `<details></details>` feature.  Is there any way to change the "Details" text that is automatically displayed to something custom?

Comment: You define a paragraph which contains the data that is displayed. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_details for an example. If you mean you want to change it after the page has loaded, use JavaScript/jquery to change the content of the paragraph.

Comment: The jsfiddle you linked to has 2 external references. When you test locally do you have those 2 references? Also pick what you help with, your original question or your new one.

Comment: Oh look at that, a whole sidebar of information.  Brilliant!

Comment: What are you on about?

Comment: You should not change the question to a different question. When you have got a correct answer to the question you asked, mark it as accepted. Post a new question separately (though you might refer to the earlier question if that’s relevant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Details" is displayed by default if you do not supply a `<summary>` element; to change this, simply use `<summary>` (thanks to Jukka K. Korpela for pointing out the default display in the comments). Keep in mind that `<details>` is not well-supported; if you do want to use the tag:

```
<details class="mydetails">
    <summary>This is the text that show</summary>
    <p>This is the text that will show when you click on the summary text</p>
</details>
```

If you want to edit the text after page load, I would recommend just using jQuery:

```
$('.mydetails summary').html('Change the text to this');
```

Now that you've added the jsfiddle:

If you want to use bootstrap, that's fine; in this case, it's actually preferred due to lack of support for `<details>`.  Make sure you have included the bootstrap css and js and that you're not getting 404 errors.

Here is a fiddle that shows the html and jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/Dc6jF/128/

Comment: The `details` element implementation in Chrome (the only implementation I’ve seen) uses the default text “Details” after the arrow (triangle), in the absence of a `summary` element.